# How to edit accent material dark in android

Tags: java, android, colors, themes

I changed the accent color. here's my code.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

But things like radio buttons haven't changed.  the code in the generated values.xml file has all these colors that I can't edit in the theme editor (in AndroidStudio.)

Like:

```
<color name="accent_material_dark">@color/material_deep_teal_200</color>
<color name="accent_material_light">@color/material_deep_teal_500</color>
```

My target is 22 and my minimum is 15... I don't know what that effects -_-

How do I edit those values?

Answer (score 0):

To define color values in colors.xml as

```
<color name="accent_material_dark">#999999</color>
<color name="accent_material_light">#787877</color>
```

> Just replace  @color/material_deep_teal_200 with color value.

And update your style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_material_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you can't update the values file because it's generated.  I tried that it just resets the next time I build.